# How to implement new instruction in linux KVM at unused x86 opcode

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, qemu, kvm, cpuid

As a part of understanding virtualization, I am trying to extend the support of KVM and defin a new instruction. The instruction will use previously unused opcodes. 
ref- ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html.

Now, lets say an instruction like 'CPUID' (which causes a vm-exit) and i want to add a new instruction, say - 'NEWCPUID', which is similar to 'CPUID' in priviledge and is trapped by hypervisor, but will differ in  the implementation.

After going through some online resources, I was able to understand how to define new system calls, but I am not sure about which all files in linux source code do I need to add the code for NEWCPUID? Is there a better way than only relying on 'find' command?

I am facing below challenges: 
1. Which all places in linux source code do I need to add code?
2. Not sure how this new instruction can be mapped to a previously unused opcode?

As I am completely new to this field and willing to learn this, can someone explain me in short how to go about this task? I will need the right direction to achieve this. If there is a reference/tutorial/blog describing the process, it will be of great help!

Comment: Hang on, AFAIK, KVM doesn't actually do any emulation. How are you proposing you add a 'new instruction'? Are you trying to use an invalid opcode to trigger a CPU exception?

Comment: I think he's talking about [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kvm/kvm_emulate.h), you still have to kind of handle privileged instructions after all. Not sure if this faulting is supposed to also work for "standard" illegal opcode trapping.

Answer (score 1):

Here are answers to some of your questions:

1. ... but I am not sure about which all files in linux source code do I need to add the code for NEWCPUID?
   A - The right place to add emulation for KVM is arch/x86/kvm/emulate.c. Take a look at how opcode_table[] is defined and the hooks to the functions that they execute. The basic idea is the guest executes and undefined instruction such as "db 0xunused"; this is results in an exit since the instruction is undefined. In KVM, you look at the rip from the VMCS/VMCB and determine if it's an instruction KVM knows about (such as NEWCPUID) and then KVM calls x86_emulate_instruction().
2. ...Is there a better way than only relying on 'find' command?
   A - Yes, pick an example system call and then use a symbol cross reference such as cscope.
3. ...n me in short how to go about this task?
   A - As I mentioned in 1, first of all find a way for the guest to attempt to execute this unused opcode (such as the db trick). I think the assembler will trying to reject unknown opcodes. So, that the first step. Second, check whether your instruction causes an vmexit(). For this, you can use tracing. Tracing emits a lot of output, so, you have to use some filter options. If tracing is overwhelming, simply printk something in vmx_handle_exit (vmx.c). Finally, find a way to hook to your custom function from here. KVM already has handle_exception() to handle guest exceptions; that would be a good place to insert your custom function. See how this function calls emulate_instruction to emulate an exception to be injected to the guest.

I have deliberately skipped some of the questions since I consider them essential to figure out yourself in the process of learning. BTW, I don't think this may not be the best way to understand virtualization. A better way might be to write your own userspace hypervisor that utlizes kvm services via /dev/kvm or maybe just a standalone hypervisor.